Groups members by profile pictures in laravel jetstream
I have two tables in my laravel jetstream project.
Tables: Projets, teachers and students with relation HasMany, BelongTo. I tried to show projects tables with all students assigned to particular project just like this in image...

Student model:
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

Project model:
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
}

I successfully get the number of students assigned to project, but how to show picture like in image above?
$project->students->count() 

I am using laravel with livewire, and jetstream.. so user profile would be access like this:
<img src="{{ Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" class="w-16 h-16 rounded-full mr-4">

Please any idea how to fix or do it? Thanks.

This is really more of a styling question.
A Flexbox container should do the trick.
<td>
    <dl class="flex -space-x-2">
        <dt class="sr-only">Students</dt>
        @foreach ($project->students->take(4) as $student)
        <dd>
            <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="{{ $student->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ $student->name }}">
        </dd>
        @endforeach
        @if ($project->students->count() > 4)
        <dd>
            <div class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full bg-gray-700 ring-2 ring-gray-700 text-white text-[10pt] flex items-center content-center justify-center">
                <span class="-ml-0.5">+{{ ($project->students->count() - 4) }}</span>
            </div>
        </dd>
        @endif
    </dl>
</td>

